# Export Values from MATLAB workspace to CSV or XLS

Tags: excel, matlab, csv, export

I would like to be able to export the Value from each Name in the Workspace using MATLAB.

I have some questions, which then sets the variables in the workspace. I have tried `xlswrite` but I have been unsuccessful in being able to export the file. I don't think that it would export just the value, which I would like it to do.

```
% Construct a questdlg with three options
choiceprepq = 'Which animal do you like?';
choiceprep = questdlg('Which animal do you like?', 'Which animal do you like?', 'Dog', 'Cat','Fish');
% Handle response
switch choiceprep
case 'Dog'
    disp([choiceprep ' Dog Selected.'])
case 'Cat'
    disp([choiceprep ' Cat Selected.'])
case 'Fish'
    disp([choiceprep ' Fish Selected.'])
end

alldata= whos('global');
filename='Test.xls';
xlswrite(filename,alldata)
```

Is there any way to export the question and the value which the user selects from the question boxes as an Excel file? Not the name of the variable, `choiceprep`, but its value.

An example in this case would be:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4cF2.png]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless you actually declare `choiceprepq` and `choiceprep` as global variables, using `whos('global')` won't give you those two. It's not necessary here anyways, because you already know the variables you want.

Also, you're using `questdlg`wrong, you need to specify your default answer, so it should be like this:

```
% syntax :  button = questdlg('qstring','title', default)
choiceprepq = 'Which animal do you like?';
choiceprep = questdlg(choiceprepq, choiceprepq, 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Dog');
```

When you do `xlswrite`, it actually only writes the values held by the variables. In your case, you can easily store the question and answer into an xls file by this:

```
filename = 'Test.xls';
xlswrite(filename, {choiceprepq, choiceprep})
```

The curly braces turn the two variables into a 1x2 cell array whose values can be easily written into xls file by `xlswrite`.

`xlswrite` does not seem to work properly on Mac OS. Here's a MATLAB file exchange submission that's supposed to help : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38591-xlwrite--generate-xls-x--files-without-excel-on-mac-linux-win

Comment: I gave your suggestion a go, it worked, but each letter is in a cell. Instead of the example screenshot shown. Any possible workaround for this?

Comment: Do you mean each cell in the resulting xls file contains only one character? What do you see on the MATLAB command window if you type in `{choiceprepq, choiceprep}` ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what happens! I typed in what you asked and this is the response: It gives the variable and then the value. So choiceprepq = the question asked and choiceprep is the answer the user chooses. I checked the XLS file again, but still one character per cell. Going from left to right, using the A, B, C etc and column number 1.

Comment: What I was asking is typing only `{choiceprepq, choiceprep}` into MATLAB command window and see what answer it gives you. Does it give you 1x2 cell array?

Comment: It gives ans: 1*2 cell

Comment: One way to produce such results as you described is to use brackets `[]` instead of curly braces `{}`. If you do `xlswrite(filename, [choiceprepq, choiceprep])` you'll end up with xls file that contains a single character in each cell. Are you sure you do exactly the same things as I posted ? Or did you actually use brackets in your xlswrite command?

Comment: I tried both brackets and curly brackets, yet still had the same results. I think that because I am on OSX, it does not work properly. During this process it has always been saving as CSV.